# Multiple Checkboxes Python HTML SQL

Tags: python, html, sql, checkbox

I have multiple check boxes and I want to allow to user to select multiple and the results to be displayed: Here is the HTML:

```
<form action= "antisearch.py"> 

 <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="b">b<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="c">c<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="d">d<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="e">e<br>
 <input type= submit value = "Search"/> <input type= reset value = "Clear"/>
```

And here is the python 2.7

```
form =cgi.FieldStorage() 

my_a=form.getlist("a") 


     db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="", db="project")
     cursor=db.cursor() 
     print "Results for the a(s) : <br>"
     sql = "select * FROM table name where a= '%s'" %(my_a)  
     cursor.execute(sql) 
     rows = cursor.fetchall()  
     for row in rows:
       print row
       print "<br>"

      db.close()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe I may need a loop but how? and where? Thanks

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about `SQL`s `IN` operator?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking. Is it that you're not getting the right results when you query the DB based on the checkboxes the user selects?